# How to vectorize process of spltting vector

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have a vector of numbers (here random). I'd like to calculate the consecutive relation of something (here means to clarify example) on the left and right side of each number in a vector.

Here is a procedural example. I'm interested in the vectorized form.

```py
from numpy.random import rand
import numpy as np
numbers = rand(40)

k=np.zeros(numbers.shape)
for i in range(*numbers.shape):
     k[i]=np.mean(numbers[:i])/np.mean(numbers[i:])
```

This example will return nan in the first iteration but it is not a problem now.

Comment: The solution depends on the precise nature of the operation you want to compute. If it is the means, as in your example, then Divakar has posted a solution for that. But if your operation is different and this was only for the example, then the solution would be different (if possible at all). There is no general good solution for that "problem type".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized way -

```
n = len(numbers)    
fwd = numbers.cumsum()/np.arange(1,n+1)
bwd = (numbers[::-1].cumsum()[::-1])/np.arange(n,0,-1)
k_out = np.r_[np.nan,fwd[:-1]]/bwd
```

Optimizing a bit further with one `cumsum`, it would be -

```
n = len(numbers)
r = np.arange(1,n+1)

c = numbers.cumsum()
fwd = c/r
b = c[-1]-c
bwd = np.r_[1,b[:-1]]/r[::-1]
k_out = np.r_[np.nan,fwd[:-1]]/bwd
```

Comment: But it only solves this specific example with mean. In fact, I asked about consecutive relation of something on the left and right side of the split vector. I gave `mean` to create reproducible and straightforward example. So I assume that there is no general solution or there is no solution at all  as @jdehesa suggest

Comment: @jarekj71 There's no magical solution that solves for any general problem. It's all case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time and there is a simple and universal solution: numpy.vectorize with `excluded` parameter, where vector designated to be split must be excluded from vectorisation. The example still uses np.mean but can be replaced with any function:

```py
def split_mean(vect,i):
    return np.mean(vect[:i])/np.mean(vect[i:])

v_split_mean = np.vectorize(split_mean)
v_split_mean.excluded.add(0)

numbers = np.random.rand(30)
indexes = np.arange(*numbers.shape)

v_split_mean(numbers,indexes)
```

Comment: How does `np.vectorize` improve upon the existing for-loop? As the docs state that `np.vectorize` is essentially looping under the hoods, I would be surprised to see any noticeable improvement.